# Attr.ownerElement meaning?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I am coding in javascript and I am also using knockout. I received this message: 'Attr.ownerElement' is deprecated and has been removed from DOM4. I don't understand what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it just means that you shouldn't use `ownerElement` property of an attribute in your code.

In MDN they say:

> **ownerElement** This property has been removed from Firefox 29. Since you can only get
>   Attr objects from elements, you should already know the owner.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Attr

So, did you use `ownerElement` in your code? Maybe some of the libs you use?

Comment: In my part, I did not use the the ownerElement. I don't know about other people's work, since I am an intern and quite beginner to their framework.

Comment: What a ridiculously arrogant statement from MDN. It's simply not true: you (the author of a bit of code) can get Attr objects from another bit of code written by someone else.

Comment: In this context the owner of an attribute would be an element, not an author of the code.